# Few sites are shown as Certificate is obsolete in Chrome(https is struck off). But they're marked as green in IE

Tags: tls, web-browser, websites

For example, for few sites the 'https' part of website is [image: struck off] when loaded through Chrome (installed in workplace) states that the connection is certified but it also states that the resources in the page is vulnerable to Man in the middle attack.

**However, from my home I am able to access the site and it is marked with 'Green lock'.**

I suspect installation/certificate present in Chrome (in workplace) needs attention. Is there anyway I can make the browser to load the page with green lock.

Comment: Chrome uses a different and more aggressive approach to HTTPS rating. I've tried to break it down and provide links to sources in my answer to this question: 2015-11-27, [*SSL certificates using modern cipher suite vs obsolete cipher suite*](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106625/ssl-certificates-using-modern-cipher-suite-vs-obsolete-cipher-suite)

Comment: The explanation was helpful. However, is there anyway that I can get green lock again. I am a bit thrown when I see my bank website is projected as 'unsafe'.

Comment: Can you add more detail to the question? Such as: Screenshot of detailed Chrome report. Screenshot of certificate chain. Name of website.